# Javascript blocks are not supported in a Qt Quick UI form

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

I'm trying to do a very simple Qt Quick application.

Qt Creator automatically creates a `MainForm.ui.qml` file, in which I put my UI components, such as a `TextField`.

When the content of this `TextField` is changed, I want to call a invokable method of a C++ `QObject`.

Here is what I did :

```
TextField {
    ...<snip>...

    onTextChanged: {
        var Result = myCppObj.doStuff(text)
        lblOutput.text = Result
    }
}
```

When I start my application, it is working fine.

But the `doStuff(text)` call is underlined in red, showing the following message :

> Javascript blocks are not supported in a Qt Quick UI form (M223).

And I cannot edit my UI with the designer tool any more.

Any idea why and how to solve this ?

Comment: What is myCppObj? Did you expose this object from `C++` to `QML`. Does it have `doStuff()` method and does it marked as `Q_INVOCABLE`? Please post all suitable code, you are 10.7k, not a newbye.

Comment: Yes, `myCppObj` is exposed and have a `doStuff()` function marked as `Q_INVOKABLE`. As mentioned, the code is working fine, I can compile and run it.

Comment: The question is the answer. UI files are meant to be used ONLY with the designer (which does not work pretty well with imperative JS). You can surely write UI files by hand but they cannot, in any way, contain imperative statements. Just remove the `.ui` or use common `.qml` files if you want to mix declarative types and imperative code. That's it. Also, you can edit `.qml` file with the designer, as long as no imperative code is contained.